# Impersonation for Accessing Gmail API

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, impersonation, gmail-api

I have generated Access Token through
OAuth by authenticating with admin account then trying to fetch all the
labels with use of Gmail API
(https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/gmail/v1/gmail.users.labels.list)
for other user in same domain. But facing issue with an error : Delegation
denied for xyz@domain.com.

Below is the code:

```
string uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token";
            string results = string.Empty;
            string responseString = null;
            using (var clientForToken = new HttpClient())
            {
                var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

                values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"));
                values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", code));
                //values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("sub", "pluto@metamini.com"));
                values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"])));
                values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"])));
                values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:6402/Home/ClaimExchangeServerAccessToken"));
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

                var response = clientForToken.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
                responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }

            var newToken = AccessTokenFromJson(responseString);

            //Uri requestUri = new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?domain=mydomain.com");
            Uri requestUri = new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/xyz@mydomain.com/labels");

            var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage()
            {
                RequestUri = requestUri,
                Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            };
            httpRequest.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", newToken));
            //httpRequest.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("sub", "pluto@metamini.com");

            var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.None
            };
            var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = null;

            responseMessage = client.SendAsync(httpRequest).Result;
            Stream receiveStream = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();
```

But getting the below error response :

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Delegation denied for mickey@metamini.com"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Delegation denied for mickey@metamini.com"
 }
}
```

Please help me out somebody.

Comment: Did you follow the steps for domain wide delegation here https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#formingclaimset. Also, instead of giving email address when sending request, try giving "me" in request and see if it succeed.

Comment: Thanks SGC for your inputs. I am able to impersonate the user by following your steps.

Answer (score 1):

It wont be possible to login with one user and get control of other users gmail account, even when you are admin.

You have to use server2server communication like it is described here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

When everything is configured right you can call the APIs on behalf of any user like in this node.js example:

```
let keyFile = "../googlekey.json"
    let scopes = [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic"
    ]
    let emailToLoginWith = "theUserYouWantToReadTheMails@for.com"
    let fs = require("fs")
    let google = require('googleapis');
    // Load client secrets from a local file.
    fs.readFile(keyFile, function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
            return;
        }

        authorize(JSON.parse(content));
    });

    var authorize = function(credentials) {
        var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');
        var auth = new googleAuth();
        var oAuth2Client = new auth.OAuth2();

        var jwt = new google.auth.JWT(
            credentials.client_email,
            null,
            credentials.private_key,
            scopes,
            emailToLoginWith        //this is the user on which behalf the service accounts logs in
        );
        jwt.authorize(function(err, result) {

                    if(err){
                        return console.error(err);
                    }
                    oAuth2Client.setCredentials({
                        access_token: result.access_token
                    });

                    var service = google.gmail('v1');
                    /!* call to google server *!/
                    service.users.settings.sendAs.list({
                        auth: oAuth2Client,
                        userId: emailToLoginWith,
                    }, function(err, response) {
                        if(err){
                            console.error(err);
                        }else{
                            console.error(JSON.stringify(response))
                        }

                    })




                });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The impersonation with an `authorization_code` still works for Google Directory API:

- [https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/[user_email]](https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/%5Buser_email%5D)
- https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups
- [https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/[customer_id]/domains](https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/%5Bcustomer_id%5D/domains)